# Disable external script on mobile version

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, responsive, disable

So I used an external script for my web page by

```
<script src="fullpage.js"></script>
```

But it disables scrolling on the site. On mobile version (which is completely different) I need to disable the script to make scrolling work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need first to detect if the user is browsing from mobile or not so you can use this method

```
function isMobileDevice() {
    return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
};
```

then you can wrap your script in the file with an if statement

```
// inside your fullpage.js file

if (!isMobileDevice()) { // check if it's not a mobile device
    // put your code here
}
```

I hope this helps :)